# Replace Cell with Header Cell

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to figure out how to either substitute or replace a cell's data with existing data from a header cell.

In the most succinct way to describe it:

**If cell = 'unchecked', then replace with the cell's header cell.**

There are numerous columns so I can't specifically say replace with a specific cell for all. It would vary depending on the cell.

As in: *(not code but won't let me save request without indentation.)*
    C3=unchecked, then pull C1.
    H18=unchecked, then pull H1.
    P4=unchecked, then pull P1.

Answer (score 2):

Just cycle through the columns, replacing the term *"unchecked"* with the value found in the first row of that column.

```
dim c as long, rplc as string
rplc = "unchecked"
with activesheet
    with .cells(1, 1).currentregion
        for c = 1 to .columns.count
            with .columns(c)
                .replace what:=rplc, replacement:=.cells(1, 1).value2, _
                         lookat:=xlwhole, matchcase:=false
            end with
        next c
    end with
end with
```

This is a generic framework and is intended to give you something to get started with. Transcribe it for your own purposes and use debug (e.g. `F8`) to walk through the code to make sure it is doing what you want. If you run into trouble, come back and explain what you do not understand, what errors are occurring and what you have discovered through debug.

You will want to change the [ActiveSheet property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff822753.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) reference to an actual worksheet name.

Comment: I am not so sure op means "unchecked" as in string but perhaps a checkbox in the cell.

Comment: The OP showed no original effort. This a generic framework only and is specifically intended not to be a turn-key solution. As an avid [programming enthusiast](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), the OP should welcome the challenge to create something of their own once given the basic tools.

Comment: Not turn key solution from Jeeped??? Downvoted =P Btw, you know any reference material I can read up on `workbooks.open`?

Comment: Here is [Workbooks.Open method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa195811(v=office.11).aspx) and [Workbooks.OpenText method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837097.aspx).

Comment: Thanks but I was reading [a more recent version](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194819.aspx) and it's not really helpful. Let me clarify. I need something very nuanced. Like discuss inner workings/memory swap/whatever jargon I don't know with regards to the function.

Comment: Don't think I have anything off the top of my head at the moment but I will keep it (and you) in mind.

Comment: Thank you Jeeped. I am very new to this and your guidance is appreciated.